# Is $P=NP$ even if we need infinitely many algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, p-vs-np

If $P=NP$ was proven with an algorithm, would that have to mean that there is **one** algorithm that has to work for all inputs of length $n$?

More specifically, what if there were infinitely many polynomial time algorithms for $n=1,2,3,...$, but no algorithm would work for more than one value $k=n$. I don't mean that $n$ would be fixed, but that for each greater $n$ we would have to modify or construct a new algorithm that solves the problem in polynomial time.

I am thankful for any answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with your first question:

> If $P=NP$ was proven with an algorithm, would that have to mean that there is **one** algorithm that has to work for all inputs of length $n$?

Yes, in order for $P$ to equal $NP$, there has to be *one* algorithm for all inputs. It can't be infinitely many algorithms that each solve some subset of the problem.

For your more specific question, though, you may be surprised: we already do have an algorithm that solves SAT for each *specific* value of $n$ and runs in polynomial time! In fact, we have an algorithm for each specific $n$ that works in constant time. Take $n = 3$, for example. Then just write out all the possible inputs of length $3$, and make a table of all the answers for each input. The algorithm just looks at the input, queries the table, and returns the result:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{input} & \text{answer} \\
000 & 0 \\
001 & 1 \\
010 & 1 \\
011 & 0 \\
\cdots
\end{array}
\\
\text{Algorithm: on input $x$ of length 3, return the answer given in the above table.}
$$

What went wrong here? The problem lies in what we mean by **polynomial time.** Hidden in the word "polynomial" is that we usually mean **polynomial in $n$**, i.e. it has to run in time that is a polynomial function of the input length. If the input length is a fixed constant, then it no longer makes sense to ask for a polynomial time algorithm: **all algorithms (no matter how fast or slow) will be polynomial time** since there are only finitely many possible inputs we care about, so the running time is always bounded by a constant.

---

**Addendum.** You raise an interesting question in the comments. My initial interpretation of it was, what if we require that the algorithm for each $n$ runs in a fixed polynomial $p(n)$ (so the polynomial upper bound has to be the same for every $n$)?
To this the answer is still that we can already do this, because we can hardcode the table in the program so that it runs in exactly $n$ steps (the time to read the input). Think of it as the following program:

```
ANSWER_TABLE = [000: 0, 001: 1, 010: 1, 011: 0, ...]
On input x:
  return ANSWER_TABLE[x]
```

Now the program size is $2^n$, sure, but the program runs in time $n$. You could also explicitly write out a giant set of nested if-then-elses instead of hardcoding the table.
Anyway, we have an algorithm for each $n$ that solves SAT and runs in at most $n$ steps.

But you still would object that the program size is still exponential in $n$.
If you also require that the program itself has size polynomial in $n$, then I am not sure if it is possible anymore. That may be related to the field of circuit complexity.

Comment: Okay, I get that the definition of polynomial time makes a fixed n useless, but in your example the table is very large. If there were smaller tables, polynomially sized ones, what would that imply? Thanks for your answer, really made it clear.

Comment: @Dude The table is large, but it can be hardcoded in the program. Because the table is hardcoded, all it takes to run the program is to read the input ($n$ steps) and immediately output the answer. So it is polynomially sized independent of $n$. I'll clarify this.

Comment: I added some thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for the additional thoughts on this! I am still wondering if it is possible. I think in the end my question is about data compression then, but I also read somewhere that you cannot compress random data? So if we want to do it for **any** input bits then it shouldn't be possible?.. Probably, I am missing many things on that topic.

Comment: Okay, I thought about it again and I still have a question, I am very interested in the answer:
Let's say you could prove that there is an algorithm that runs in polynomial time for every input length $n$ **and** the sizes of these infinitely many algorithms grow polynomially and are all polynomial in $n$.
So, instead of having one algorithm to prove $P=NP$ we would have infinitely many to do so. I know it sounds like it doesn't make sense, but I can't come up with an answer.
Does the answer then depend on how long you neeed to come up with the algorithm that adds all these algos together?

Comment: I think this answer fails to address the question of P = NP, and the relation between the question of P = NP, and one particular polynomial algorithm for one particular problem. P is a class of problems. NP is a class of problems. Every problem which is P is also NP; the question is, does there exist a problem which is NP but not P? We don't know. However, we do know that there exist some problems which are "NP-complete"; meaning that if we can find a polynomial-time algo for an NP-complete problem, then this algorithm would immediately translate into poly-time algo for every other NP problem.

Comment: In particular, the OP's question contains the phrase "If P=NP was proven with an algorithm"; I think a good answer should at least try to explain how the existence of a particular algorithm could be a proof that P=NP.

Comment: Hmm, I can't follow you Stef, to be  honest. I know that if we can solve one NP-complete problem in polynomial time we can solve them all in polynomial time.
Back to my train of thought. If we know there are polynomial time algorithms for any input length $n$ what would that mean in your view? 6005 says it wouldn't prove $P=NP$ which I thought was well explained. Above I elaborated on my original question a bit further.

Comment: @Stef sure, that could be explained better -- throughout this answer, I assume the reader knows that proving P = NP is equivalent to showing there is a polynomial-time algorithm for SAT.

Comment: @Dude It would be great to ask your updated question (comment "Okay, I thought about it again and I still have a question") as a new post. I think it's a good one.

Comment: @Dude *"If we know there are polynomial time algorithms for any input length "* This sentence is self-contradictory. If you constraint input to have length exactly n for a given n, then it doesn't make sense to talk about "polynomial time". Polynomial in what? When we say "algorithm A solves problem P in polynomial time" we mean that the algorithm finds the correct answer *for any input*, and the time it takes is polynomial in the length of the input. If the length of the input is not a variable, then there is no such thing as "a polynomial in the length of the input".

Comment: Okay, that does make a lot sense @Stef. Though, what if all these infinitely many lookup tables (since n is fixed) exist and the lookup table with the greatest length for $n$ (being $n=\infty$) would solve all instances.
I guess it wouldn't quite coun't as a practical solution, but would that maybe still count technically? Like, we know that there is this infinite big algorithm that could solve our problem in polynomial time, but the algorithm is too big, but polynomially bounded by $n=\infty$.
Does that sound like a paradox? Or is it clear that such an algorithm wouldn't prove $P=NP$?

Comment: @Dude theoretically and practically, there is no such thing as an "instant access infinite look-up table". Browsing the table would certainly take some time.

Comment: Yeah, it would take polynomial time. Do you think that because $n=\infty$ was necessary so the search time would be infinite too and therefore the algorithm wouldn't count?

Comment: $n = \infty$?? The size of any input is finite. There's no such thing as $n = \infty$.

Comment: Yes, but to satisfy all inputs we would need a program that is made for an infinite big input length. I agree there is something wrong in my reasoning. Thanks for the answers though, I will maybe ask this question later as a new thread, if I don't find my errors.